# Раскрыть каталог на сайте drom через запрос XHR средствами python

Tags: python, парсер, xhr

Здравствуйте уважаемые коллеги.

Помогите решить задачу,
сгенерировать запрос, чтобы получить ответ в виде html кода
с раскрытым каталогом на сайте [drom.ru](https://www.drom.ru/)

если кликнуть из браузера по ссылке "Показать все" то каталог раскрывается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Рисунок 1 - каталог сайта drom.ru
Как это реализовать через запрос?

```
url = 'https://tyumen.drom.ru/auto/'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

Пытался отследить XHR но безуспешно, использовать Selenium с браузерами и функциями кликов очень не хочется...

Answer (score 1):

Нужен исключительно блок с каталогом или вся страница с учетом открытого каталога?

Если полностью html страница с раскрытым каталогом то вот рабочий вариант:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def main() -> None:
    BaseUrl = 'https://www.drom.ru/catalog/'
    response = requests.get(BaseUrl)
    bsLXML = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    with open('domru_catalog.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(bsLXML))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Если будет ругаться на отсутствие парсера, то установи через pip или poetry, смотря через что ты работаешь модуль lxml

Весь рабочий процесс, в моем случае выглядит так:

```
mkdir parseDomru
cd parseDomru
poetry init
poetry env use python3.11
poetry shell
poetry add bs4 requests lxml
nvim main.py
python3.11 main.py
```

Если нужен HTML только div блока в котором находится каталог, то так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def main() -> None:
    BaseUrl = 'https://www.drom.ru/catalog/'
    response = requests.get(BaseUrl)
    bsLXML = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    with open('domru_catalog.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(bsLXML))

    ''' 
        Парсим только div  в котором прописан каталог и пишем полученный
        HTML в файл
    '''
    catalogDomru = bsLXML.find_all('div', {'class': 'css-18clw5c ehmqafe0'})
    with open('domru_catalog_div.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(catalogDomru))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. Задача получить ответ с блоком <div class="css-5y3up5 ehmqafe0" - данный блок с развернутым каталогом, а при class="css-18clw5c ehmqafe0" - в блоке каталог свернут

Comment: можно конечно зайти внутрь каждой категории и собрать всю необходимую информацию, но хотелось бы сократить количество запросов на сервер и собирать все с одной странички

Comment: Тогда, почитай про соуп и просто вычлени нужный див, потом найди css свойство и при получении html кода просто атоматом туда впиши нужный стиль на визибл ) find_all как раз проходит все что вложено одним запросом